# boost::detail::core_typeid_ in binary

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, obfuscation

I see im my release binary written in C++ a lot of strings similar to this one:

const char *__cdecl boost::detail::core_typeid_,class boost::_bi::list3,struct boost::arg<1>,struct boost::arg<2> > > >::name(void)

Does anyone know how I can get rid of them?

Comment: Why [tag:obfuscation]? Is the binary stripped? Can you define NDEBUG to potentially reduce (logging) macro use? Are you storing `boost::bind` expressions in a `boost::any` (possibly via indirections like boost::function)? IOW: SSCCE required

Comment: maybe obfuscation is not a good tag, I defined it as NDEBUG and all debug informations are off so it's supposed to be stripped.  I didn't understand the last question.

Comment: http://sscce.org or e.g. stackoverflow.com/help/mcve